# Saving an int to internal memory xcode iphone dev

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a value `int` called `score` and i want to save this to the phone's memory so that this would be the high score that is never deleted even id the game gets closed and re opend,

can somebody suggest a way for this to happen?

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSUserDefaults`.  It might be the simplest way, depending on what else you need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults`.

To save:

```
int score = 12345;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"HIGHSCORE"];
```

To load:

```
int score = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HIGHSCORE"] integerValue];
```

Comment: You can use `setInteger:forKey`, `integerForKey` if you prefer. Both do the same thing, this one keeps the access consistent with `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the Apple documentation for `NSUserDefaults`

See [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: score forKey: @"Score"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view,  easy way to save the best score is thru saving the score as a string value and recall in it back when it is need.

```
//this example assume that high score is in text    
NSString *SaveHighScore = HighScore.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaultsHighScore = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultsHighScore setObject:SaveHighScore forKey:@"savedHighScore"];
    [defaultsHighScore synchronize];
```

and to recall

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaultsHighScore = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadHighScore = [defaultsHighScore objectForKey:@"savedHighScore"];
[HighScore setText :loadHighScore];
```